# Boostrap Responsive Menu Not Working

Tags: theming

I'm having an issue with my menu on the responsive size. For some reason my menu doesn't collapse so I cannot see any of my items on my menu on a tablet or a mobile. Using the inspect element I check and all the pages from my menu are in the html but the collapsing part is not working anymore. I'm currently using the [Project Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) .

Can anyone provide me some tips on how to troubleshoot this problem? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Upgrade you jQuery to 1.9+ as the documentation at Project Bootstrap requires. It is at 1.7.1 currently.

Comment: @J.Reynolds Using the Jquery_update module I change my Jquery version to 1.10 and this still not working. Also, I clear caches and still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the HTML on your homepage there, I'm seeing you're loading bootstrap in your `<head>` section, and then calling jQuery from near the footer, way down on line 223 (that'd be the line `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. That's why I'm at least seeing the error `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery`.  You want to load jQuery before you load Bootstrap, so ultimately your `<head>` should include the two lines:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

I hope this at least gets you closer.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. Good spotting. Though as he is using Bootstrap 3 he needs at least jQuery 1.9+ as well.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I was using the advagg module and this change the Jquery_Update to 1.7. I'm not currently using this module so I remove it and the menu is working properly. Thank you guys.